# base_url codeigniter solution

Tags: codeigniter, web, base-url

I use the base url in code igniter like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>../../includes/images/logo_fosss.png">
```

The above code runs correctly.

But sometimes this code gives an error, and the code must be changed like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>../../../includes/images/logo_fosss.png">
```

I've put a folder 'includes' in the root (same place level as application and system).

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**base_url()** should be used for *absolute* URLs.

If you include **../** you are stating that the URL is *relative*.

I think your code should be something like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>includes/images/logo_fosss.png">
```

or like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>/includes/images/logo_fosss.png">
```

Make sure your **includes** folder is in the root folder of your Codeigniter install.

For more information, check out this article:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3